# Can not delete directory by mask in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I try to delete directory in 'foo/dir' with name 'public-*someHash*'. 'SomeHash' was created dynamically (eg 'dsflsdfn') and always new. I tried to use 'fileTree' but directory still present. There is my code:

```
tasks.create(name: 'delete', type : Delete) {
        delete fileTree(dir: 'foo/dir/', include: 'public-*/**')
}
```

What is wrong with my mask?

UDP: I have similar task in Ant and all works fine:

```
 <target name="delete">
        <delete includeemptydirs="true">
          <fileset dir="foo/dir/">
            <include name="public-*/**"/>
          </fileset>
        </delete>
 </target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Apologies, as original answer was based on a misreading of the question.

Here's one way to do it, but not the most elegant:

```
task myDelete(type: Delete) {
    def files = new HashSet()

    new File('foo/dir').eachFile { file ->
        if (file.isDirectory() && (file.name ==~ /public-.*/)) {
            files << file
        } 
    }

    delete files
}
```

Comment: it doesn't help. Interesting that println fileTree(dir: 'foo/bar') show 'directory 'src/main/webapp''

Comment: My apologies. I misread the question. Please try the new answer. (This assumes that the target directories are in `foo/dir` and not in subdirectories.)